# Prevent page title from auto-updating in Joomla 1.5?

Tags: javascript, joomla, overriding, title, joomla1.5

I'm working on a messed up project of Joomla where most of the things  are made in core, like passing `option=com_admn&view=displayUsers`. We've a blog page where all the blogs are listed. As I can clearly see, the title of the page is set to `Blogs list- ProjectName` while the document is loading but as soon as the page is loaded completely, the title is over riden and is set to `ProjectName`. When I checked the same in FireBug, I found that `title` was being updated every 2 secs, I guess, by javascript.
I've tried changing global as well as article and menu settings but that doesn't seem to help. Please enlighten me by pointing out the issue and the solution.

Comment: Have you tried to track down the JS file that is overriding the title?

Comment: If I  had, I wouldn't been asking the question!

Comment: Well if it's a JS file, how are we supposed to help debug or know which file it is? There are loads of JS files that get shipped with Joomla and possibly the template so it's very hard to tell. Can you provide a link to your site? Else all I can recommend is firstly to check all JS files that belong to the template. You also said `where most of the changes were made in core`, assuming you mean the Joomla core files were changed, which is another reason why help on this topic is nearly next to impossible.

Comment: Okay. You may goto www.parentune.com and see. Probably I might not have been able to trace the JS, but I guess you could. Let me know if you find a sol.

Comment: At the homepage(landing) page itself, the (browser) title is something else (if you check it at a slow connection), but as soon as the page is completely loaded, the title is changed to default 'parentune'. If you may check it in firebug, you'd see the title being updated each second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I found the issue.

You have a JS file called **chatnew.js** which I believe is part of the comments section below the blog post.

```
/templates/learnmile/js/chatnew.js
```

This file contains the following function:

```
function blink(selector)
{
    if($(selector).hasClass("chatbord"))
    {
        $(selector).removeClass("chatbord");
        document.title = $(selector).html();
    }
    else
    {
        $(selector).addClass("chatbord");
        document.title = "Parentune";   // <<< HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    }

    setTimeout(function(){blink(selector)},2000);
}
```

I have added a comment in the code above which is replacing the title.

Comment: Hell man, you're the savior! Thanks a ton. You saved my day. Really really thank you so much :D :)